# Can force:recordData query related parent fields?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lookup, parent, force-recorddata

Anyone found a way to select parent fields with force:recordData?
It would be great to have something like this:

```
<force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetRecord="{!v.child}"
                  layoutType="FULL" fields="parent__r.Name" recordUpdated="{!c.init}" />

init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var child= cmp.get("v.child");

    if(child) {
        console.log(child.fields.parent__r.Name);
    }
}
```

results is `undefined`

Comment: What does this prints?- `JSON.stringify(child.fields)`

Comment: threw an error, but log(child.fields) worked. 
So it seems like this did the trick:
`child.fields.parent__r.value.fields.Name.value` doesn't look good though :/

Comment: Looks like the structure ob object generated by Salesforce here is bit odd.

Comment: couldn't find any other way, thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, glad to be of any help. Its looks ugly though :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So with some help I figured out that it works, it is just a bit dirty to get the values, this is the path through the object structure:

```
child.fields.parent__r.value.fields.Name.value
```

So the `targetFields` attribute on recordData just came to my mind, and I replaced `targetRecord`. Now it works as expected:

```
<force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetFields="{!v.child}"
                  fields="parent__r.foo__c" recordUpdated="{!c.init}" />

var child = cmp.get("v.child");
console.log(child.parent__c); 
console.log(child.parent__r.Id); 
console.log(child.parent__r.Name); 
console.log(child.parent__r.foo__c);
```

**Notes:**

- `parent__r.Name` and `parent__r.Id` will ALWAYS be part of the data set
- Don't forget the namespace: `MY_NAMESPACE__parent__r.MY_NAMESPACE__foo__c`

**The max depth is 5**

`parent__r.parent2__r.parent3__r.parent4__r.parent5__r.bar__c`

Exceeding the limit will silently fail and leave your `targetFields="{!v.child}"` **null**

- Same as when you mistype field names in the `fields=""` attribute (or forgot the NS) it will tell you the miss-leading error message:

  > [Cannot read property 'parent__r' of null]

### Edit

Found it officially documented, hidden in the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm):

> Lightning Data Service supports spanned fields with a maximum depth of
>   five levels. Support for working with collections of records or for
>   querying for a record by anything other than the record ID isn’t
>   available. If you must support higher-level operations or multiple
>   operations in one transaction, use standard @AuraEnabled Apex methods.

Comment: When I add a parent field to the fields attribute of force:recordData it is not the callback for recordUpdated. But there is no error in target error. Did you encounter this behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean the update method is not called when the parent gets updated, or is it not queried when the record itself gets updated? I don't remember any issues, but I'm not sure if I had this scenario.

Comment: My mistake I was using the wrong API name for a related field. But it did not give an error. But just failed to callback on the recordUpdated event :|. With the correct API name it works fine.